# Run-time error 1004 in Excel macro: Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use this code to search for something in one sheet and move it to another. Below is my code. I keep getting this error:

```
       Run-time error '1004':
       Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, myCounter
    Dim erow, myValue As Long

    For Each ws In Sheets

    If ws.Range("C3").Value > 6 Then

    myCounter = 1
    ws.Select
    ws.Range("C3").Select

    myValue = ws.Range("C3").Value

    Worksheets("Report").Select

    erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Row

    ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1) = myValue

    nextValue = MsgBox("Value found in " & ws.Name & Chr(10) & "Continue?",       vbInformation + vbYesvbNo, ws.Name & " C3 = " & ws.Range("C3").Value)

    Select Case nextValue
    Case Is = vbYes
    Case Is = vbNo
    Exit Sub
    End Select
    End If
    Next ws

    If myCounter = 0 Then
        MsgBox "None of the sheets contains a " & Chr(10) & "value greater than 6 in cell C3 ", vbInformation, "Not Found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Why am I getting this error?

```
       **Run-time error '1004':
       Application-defined or object-defined error**
```

Comment: Please write good titles.

Comment: What line is highlighted when you get that error?

Comment: you have a spelling error in your code. `.End(x1Up)` should be `.End(xlUp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `x1Up` where you should have `xlUp`; note the `1` instead of the lower case `L`. Also the MsgBox option is `vbYesNo`, not `vbYesvbNo`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim w As Long, bFound As Boolean, nextValue As Variant
    Dim erow, myValue As Long

    For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        With Worksheets(w)
            'don't look on the Report worksheet
            If .Name <> Worksheets("Report").Name Then
                'use isnumeric to avoid confusing text and numbers
                If IsNumeric(.Range("C3").Value2) Then
                    If .Range("C3").Value2 > 6 Then
                        Worksheets("Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range("C3").Value
                        nextValue = MsgBox("Value found in " & .Name & Chr(10) & "Continue?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, .Name & " C3 = " & .Range("C3").Value)
                        bFound = True
                        Select Case nextValue
                            Case vbYes
                                'do nothing; continue
                            Case vbNo
                                'just exit the worksheet loop
                                Exit For
                        End Select
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next w

    If Not bFound Then
        MsgBox "None of the sheets contains a " & Chr(10) & "value greater than 6 in cell C3 ", vbInformation, "Not Found"
    End If

End Sub
```

The above is my version of your code. Get used to using Option Explicit to avoid typos.